# guzzle 6.+ send request with header and body

Tags: php, phalcon, guzzle

i want to send a request per guzzle.

i try this but guzzle send no request.

```
           $response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
                'auth'    => [
                        'user',
                        'pw'
                    ],
                    'headers' => [
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    ],
                    'body' => [
                        'token' => $accessToken
                    ]
                ]
            );
         $response->getBody()->getContents()
```

if i delete the body part. the request is working. but i need the body too. and i get no response. is there a possibility to see what guzzle exactly is sending?

Comment: Are you getting any sort of feedback in your php error log?

Comment: there are no new errors for today. so the code produce no output in the log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`form_params`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) instead. `body` takes a raw byte sequence.

Comment: thanks for your help. it was usefull. now i get the follwoing error msg: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::getBody(). i think the response is typ guzzleHttp\Response?

Comment: @eldios1981, it's impossible to tell something without seeing the code. It seems that you already get the body somehow, bypassing the response.

Comment: yes, i found that out too. i had something like that: $response = $client->request(...)->getBody(); deleting the getBody() works. Thank you very much for your help and fast answer